# asp.net mvc 4 with jquery-file-upload Request.Files.Count always 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I'm currently use asp.net mvc 4 ,and use jquery-file-upload to upload images,if i initialize like this:

```
        $('#fileupload').fileupload();

        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            //url: '/Admin/News/Create',
            maxFileSize: 500000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
            resizeMaxWidth: 1920,
            resizeMaxHeight: 1200,
        });
```

when select a image file,the image can preview in the borwser,but in the mvc Action Request.Files.Count is 0,that means no file uploaded.
And if i initialize like this:

```
        //$('#fileupload').fileupload();

        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            //url: '/Admin/News/Create',
            maxFileSize: 500000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
            resizeMaxWidth: 1920,
            resizeMaxHeight: 1200,
        });
```

i can't preview the image ,but the mvc Action get the file,does anyone know why?
post code for controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(NewsViewModel model, FormCollection form)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //....

            // upload image
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
                if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                    continue;
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/News/"),GUID.NewGuid()+ Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName));
                hpf.SaveAs(path);

                data.ImagePath = path;
                _iNewsService.UpdateNews(data);
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Why is the line `url: '/Admin/News/Create',` commented out?

Comment: coz i don't i want auto upload,and i'm using strongly typed view,the form has it's action assigned

Comment: @Behnam Esmaili please see the question

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem ,solved it with following :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(NewsViewModel model, FormCollection form)
    {                  
            var length = Request.ContentLength;
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, length); 

            //or for creating image from stream 

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(InputStream));
            bmp.Save("some path");  

   }
```

hope this could help.

Comment: Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(InputStream));  i've tried some other ways ,such as use Image instead of Bitmap,this line always hit exception 'Parameter is not valid'

Comment: did you mean Request.InputStream is null?

Comment: if bytes has value ,then `Request.InputStream` must has value as well.

Comment: when use Image.FromStream(stream) Bitmap.FromStream(stream) will hit that exception